# mysql - how to replace a sub-string?

Tags: mysql, regex

a field is a varchar, i want to replace a sub string of this field.

```
ab123fg => ab456fg
```

the above is just a example.
just like the sub string to be replaced.

Comment: how do you identify which part of your string needs replacing? Is it the 1st set of numbers? or characters 3,4,5 or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
REPLACE(str, 'ab123fg ', 'ab456fg')
```

**EDIT:**

MySQL doesnt have a find and replace regex function, maybe have a look at [UDFs](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)